# How can i upload more than one photo / file at once in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, upload

This function uploads photos:

```
 public function addImageForNewRecp(Request $request)
    {
        $file =  $request->file('images');

        $imageName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $imageName = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($imageName));
        $imageName = time() . $imageName;
        $file->move(public_path() . '/storage/', $imageName);

        return response()->json(["key" => $imageName]);
    }
```

**I think I need a for loop to loop all the filenames write but I couldn't figure out where to put it, please help**

Additional code:

```
 <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="recpfiles" class="recpfiles"  name="images1" accept="image/* , image/tiff" >
```

Answer (score 1):

For upload multiple files from the same input field, you just have to make a name with array like below

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="recpfiles" class="recpfiles"  name="images1[]" accept="image/* , image/tiff" >
```

In the controller use like below

```
$files = $request->file('images'); // it will return array
```

For better understanding you can follow this [article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-multiple-files-images-upload/)

Comment: when i do this, this error occurs: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given for this code:   public function store(Request $request)
    {  $data = array();
        $imageNames = $request->myImages;
        // dd($imageNames);
        $imageNames = ltrim($imageNames, ',');
        $data = explode(',', $imageNames);

Comment: see the article for understanding

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [ ] in your select name attribute

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="recpfiles" class="recpfiles"  name="images1[]" accept="image/* , image/tiff" >
```

Comment: when i do this, this error occurs: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given for this code: public function store(Request $request) { $data = array(); $imageNames = $request->myImages; // dd($imageNames); $imageNames = ltrim($imageNames, ','); $data = explode(',', $imageNames);